# Display contents of method as response to doPost

Tags: servlets, methods

Good day. I'm currently creating a simple salary calculator program in servlet where it will display the GrossPay, WithholdingTax and the NetPay of the user. The computation of calculator is correct. My problem is that after the user enters the needed data, the salary details of the user is displayed in the console of Eclipse instead in the web browser. I'm just starting to learn servlet, and a little help would be very much appreciated. The code is below.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    double hrsWorked1 = 0;
    double ratePHour1 = 0;


    if ((request.getParameter("hrsWorked") != null)||(request.getParameter("ratePHour") != null)) {
        hrsWorked1 = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("hrsWorked"));
        ratePHour1 = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("ratePHour"));

        if((hrsWorked1 < 0)||(ratePHour1 < 0)){
            out.print("<h1>Invalid amount - must be positive.</h1>");
            out.print("<h3>Click <a href='index.html'>here</a> to try again.</h3>");
        }
    }
    computeSalary(hrsWorked1, ratePHour1);
    out.close();     
}

private void computeSalary(double hrsWorked , double ratePHour) {
        double grosspay = hrsWorked * ratePHour;
        double withholdingTax; 
        double sss = 1500.00;
        double hdmf = 1000.00;
        double deductions; 
        double netpay; 

    if(grosspay <= 10000){
        withholdingTax = grosspay * .08;
        deductions = withholdingTax + hdmf + sss;
        netpay = grosspay - deductions;
        System.out.println("<h4>Gross Pay (PHP): </h4>" + grosspay );
        System.out.println("<h4>Withholding (PHP): </h4>" + withholdingTax );
        System.out.println("<h4>SSS (PHP): </h4>" + sss );
        System.out.println("<h4>HDMF (PHP): </h4>" + hdmf );
        System.out.println("<h4>Net Pay (PHP): </h4>" + netpay );
    }
    else if((grosspay >= 10001)&&(grosspay <= 15000)){
        withholdingTax = grosspay * .10;
        deductions = withholdingTax + hdmf + sss;
        netpay = grosspay - deductions;
        System.out.println("<h4>Gross Pay (PHP): </h4>" + grosspay );
        System.out.println("<h4>Withholding (PHP): </h4>" + withholdingTax );
        System.out.println("<h4>SSS (PHP): </h4>" + sss );
        System.out.println("<h4>HDMF (PHP): </h4>" + hdmf );
        System.out.println("<h4>Net Pay (PHP): </h4>" + netpay );
    }
    else if((grosspay >= 15001)&&(grosspay <= 25000)){
        withholdingTax = grosspay * .14;
        deductions = withholdingTax + hdmf + sss;
        netpay = grosspay - deductions;
        System.out.println("<h4>Gross Pay (PHP): </h4>" + grosspay );
        System.out.println("<h4>Withholding (PHP): </h4>" + withholdingTax );
        System.out.println("<h4>SSS (PHP): </h4>" + sss );
        System.out.println("<h4>HDMF (PHP): </h4>" + hdmf );
        System.out.println("<h4>Net Pay (PHP): </h4>" + netpay );
    }
    else if((grosspay >= 25001)&&(grosspay < 35000)){
        withholdingTax = grosspay * .18;
        deductions = withholdingTax + hdmf + sss;
        netpay = grosspay - deductions;
        System.out.println("<h4>Gross Pay (PHP): </h4>" + grosspay );
        System.out.println("<h4>Withholding (PHP): </h4>" + withholdingTax );
        System.out.println("<h4>SSS (PHP): </h4>" + sss );
        System.out.println("<h4>HDMF (PHP): </h4>" + hdmf );
        System.out.println("<h4>Net Pay (PHP): </h4>" + netpay );
    }
    else{
        withholdingTax = grosspay * .25;
        deductions = withholdingTax + hdmf + sss;
        netpay = grosspay - deductions;
        System.out.println("<h4>Gross Pay (PHP): </h4>" + grosspay );
        System.out.println("<h4>Withholding (PHP): </h4>" + withholdingTax );
        System.out.println("<h4>SSS (PHP): </h4>" + sss );
        System.out.println("<h4>HDMF (PHP): </h4>" + hdmf );
        System.out.println("<h4>Net Pay (PHP): </h4>" + netpay );
    }
}


}
```

Comment: if you make the call from Chrome and check the response in the network tab do you see anything in the response?

Comment: @bhspencer there's nothing displayed in Chrome. The output should be displayed in the browser, not in the console of eclipse.

Comment: @bhspencer I think the problem is in `computeSalary` method, the way I display the output of the form. I just don't know what's the right way to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your computeSalary() method is writing to System.out rather than to the variable out that you got from the response.

You need to change the computeSalary method to take your responses PrintWriter like this:

```
private void computeSalary(double hrsWorked , double ratePHour, PrintWriter out)
```

And then you need to use that instead of System.out like this:

```
out.println("<h4>Gross Pay (PHP): </h4>" + grosspay );
```

Comment: an error appeared in this line `computeSalary(hrsWorked1, ratePHour1);`. It says: The method computeSalary(double, double, PrintWriter) in the type PayrollComp is not applicable for the arguments (double, double)